# iOS - Picker controller does not open Photo Library

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, uiactionsheet

In my app, i use a UIActionSheet and UIImagePickerController. Action Sheet opens optiones (as choose photo, choose video) and Image Picker Controller opens library. This system works good for iPhone device testing but for iPad, Action Sheet works fine while Picker Controller does not.

I have set required permissions for iOS10, for camera and photo library. This cannot be the problem.

My code for selecting photo:

```
- (void)selectPhoto {

    self.imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    self.imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    self.imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage, nil];
    [self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Required delegate methods were written either. And as I mentioned, everyting works as it should do in iPhones.

When I try to open photo library first I get this warning messages:

> [Warning] <_UIPopoverBackgroundVisualEffectView 0x147c5ad0> is being
>   asked to animate its opacity. This will cause the effect to appear
>   broken until opacity returns to 1.

Nothing is broken, app is still running (not freezing). However if I try to open photo library, this time I get:

> Warning: Attempt to present   on
>    which is already presenting (null)

Then, the problem might be popover problem but I could not find the answer. 
Thank you!

Edit: My action sheet delegate method:

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    [actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:buttonIndex animated:YES];
    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0:
            [self selectPhoto];
            break;
        case 1:
            [self selectVideo];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:** I found [that](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PickinganItemfromthePhotoLibrary.html):

> On iPad, you must present the browser interface using a popover as
>   described in initWithContentViewController: and Presenting and
>   Dismissing the Popover in UIPopoverController Class Reference. If, on
>   iPad, you attempt to present the browser interface modally
>   (full-screen), the system raises an exception.

UIPopoverController is now deprecated. Thus I should use another way. If anyone can help me about this, I'd be ver happy.

Comment: Have you `dismiss` your `UIActionSheetController` before presenting `UIImagePickerController` ?

Comment: I haven't but now i did. Still the same.

Comment: Please show the additional code for dismissing the alert. You need to make sure to present the image picker in the completion. Otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

For iPad use the code to open the UIImagePicker

```
 [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

                [self presentViewController:picker animated:NO completion:nil];
            }];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of all Cocoa Keys that you can specify in your Info.plist file:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html

iOS already required permissions to access microphone, camera, and media library earlier (iOS6, iOS7), but since iOS10 the apps will crash if you don't provide the description why you are asking for the permission.

Answer (score 0):

On iPad you can't show UIImagePickerController popover over an already onscreen UIActionSheet popover.

Replace

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

with

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
```

and it must work.

And remove `[actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:buttonIndex animated:YES];`, as soon as you click on a button, `UIActionSheet` is dismissed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

To show an image picker on both the iPhone and iPad, you need to present it as a popover.

So the implementation to show your picker would change to

```
self.imagePickerController.delegate = self;
self.imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
self.imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage, nil];
self.imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover; //This is needed
self.imagePickerController.sourceView = self.view; //This is needed
[self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Do make sure your action sheet is dismissed before you present the picker.